# Mvc 4 unit testing concept

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, theory

I am trying to understand the concept of TDD in MVC 4 application.
All examples I've found over the net doesn't explained me the concept of what Unit test in a case of MVC 4 application should test.

So when you writing your unit testing , what are the main points you are trying to test in your controller?

If possible please explain on this example.

```
public class UsersIDentController : AuthorizedController
{    
    private readonly IUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public UsersIDentController(IUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            IServiceLocator serviceLocator): base(serviceLocator)
    {
    }    

    //
    // GET: /UsersIdentification/
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ShowDetails()
    {
        UsersIdentificationViewModel model = new UsersIdentificationViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If you'd be writing unit test for this controller (gettin user data) what will you test in unit test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't elaborate much about unit testing on the current example you have. Because all you got there is a single method `ShowDetails` that returns a `View` tied with `UsersIdentificationViewModel`. Since you are returning only `View` you could change the return type into `ViewResult`. Then, all you can test is if the model tied with the `View` is of type `UsersIdentificationViewModel`.

I could explain unit testing in MVC little more better if we take a simple example. If you create a fresh MVC application selecting the `internet template` you would see an `AccountController` is defined as default and it contains actions for *login*, *register*, *change password* etc.

Let's take the `LogOn` action in the `AccountController`.

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthProvider _authProvider;

    public AccountController(IAuthProvider authProvider)
    {
        _authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_authProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                _authProvider.SetCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    ...
}
```

To avoid the dependency with `FormsAuthentication` sealed class with the `AccountController` I've used an interface `IAuthProvider` to simplify the unit testing.

**IAuthProvider.cs**

```
public interface IAuthProvider
{
    bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);

    void SetCookie(string username, bool rememberMe);

    bool CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, out string error);

    bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword);

    void SignOut();
}
```

**LogOnModel.cs**

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

You can notice many **if..else** conditions in the `LogOn` action and they are good candiates for unit testing.

I would write atleast four unit tests for the action.

1. Verify on entering valid credentials the action should redirect to the passed url.
2. Verify on passing valid credentials without `returnUrl` the `AccountController` should redirect the user to the `Home` action.
3. Verify on passing invalid credentials the account controller should return view with errors.
4. Verify when there is a validation error the controller should return view with errors.

Here are the unit tests I've written using `MSTest` and `RhinoMocks`.

**AccountControllerTests.cs**

```
[TestClass]
public class AccountControllerTests
{
   private AccountController _accountController;
   private IAuthProvider _mockAuthProvider;

   [TestInitialize]
   public void SetUp()
   { 
       //** Arrange
       _mockAuthProvider = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAuthProvider>();
       _accountController = new AccountController(_mockAuthProvider);
   }

   [TestCleanup]
   public void CleanUp()
   {      
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This test is to verify on entering valid credentials the action should redirect   to the passed url.
   /// </summary>
   [TestMethod]
   public void LogOn_Action_Valid_Credentials_With_ReturnUrl_Test()
   {
       //** Arrange
       var logonModel = new LogOnModel
       {
          UserName = "trigent",
          Password = "password",
          RememberMe = true
       };

       // stub the ValidateUser to return "true" to pretend the user is valid.
       _mockAuthProvider.Stub(x => x.ValidateUser(logonModel.UserName, logonModel.Password)).Return(true);

       //** Act
       var actual = _accountController.LogOn(logonModel, "/");

       //** Assert

       // verify RedirectResult is returned from action
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(RedirectResult));

       // verify the redirect url is same as the passed one.
       Assert.AreEqual(((RedirectResult)actual).Url, "/");
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This test is to verify on passing valid credentials without returnUrl the account controller
   /// should redirect the user to the "Home" action.
   /// </summary>
   [TestMethod]
   public void LogOn_Action_Valid_Credentials_Without_ReturnUrl_Test()
   {
       //** Arrange
       var logonModel = new LogOnModel
       {
           UserName = "trigent",
           Password = "password",
           RememberMe = true
       };

       // stub the ValidateUser to return "true" to pretend the user is valid.
       _mockAuthProvider.Stub(x => x.ValidateUser(logonModel.UserName, logonModel.Password)).Return(true);

       //** Act
       var actual = _accountController.LogOn(logonModel, string.Empty);

       //** Assert

       // verify RedirectToRouteResult is returned from action
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));

       // verify the controller redirecting to "Home" action.
       var routeValues = ((RedirectToRouteResult)actual).RouteValues;
       Assert.AreEqual("Home", routeValues["controller"].ToString());
       Assert.AreEqual("Index", routeValues["action"].ToString());
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This test is to verify on passing invalid credentials the account controller should return the login view 
   /// with error messages.
   /// </summary>
   [TestMethod]
   public void LogOn_Action_Invalid_Credentials_Test()
   {
       //** Arrange
       var logonModel = new LogOnModel
       {
          UserName = "trigent",
          Password = "password",
          RememberMe = true
       };

       // stub the ValidateUser to return "false" to pretend the user is invalid.
       _mockAuthProvider.Stub(x => x.ValidateUser(logonModel.UserName, logonModel.Password)).Return(false);

       //** Act
       var actual = _accountController.LogOn(logonModel, string.Empty);

       //** Assert

       // verify ViewResult is returned from action
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));

       // verify the controller throws error.
       var modelStateErrors = _accountController.ModelState[""].Errors;
       Assert.IsTrue(modelStateErrors.Count > 0);
       Assert.AreEqual("The user name or password provided is incorrect.", modelStateErrors[0].ErrorMessage);
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This test is to verify when there is a validation error the controller should return the same login view.
   /// </summary>
   [TestMethod]
   public void LogOn_Action_Invalid_Input_Test()
   {
       //** Arrange
       _accountController.ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "UserName is Required.");

       //** Act
       var actual = _accountController.LogOn(new LogOnModel(), string.Empty);

       //** Assert

       // verify ViewResult is returned from action
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you test the ShowDetails Method, you could verify if it returns a View with the model of the correct type.

To do so, you can use [MVC Contrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/), which has Unit Test Assertions you can use for it. You can find all the unit test documentation here: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper&referringTitle=Documentation